# Dict Observation Space for Stable Baselines3 Not Working

Tags: python-3.x, openai-gym, stable-baselines

I've created a minimal reproducible example below, this can be run in a new Google Colab notebook for ease. Once the first install finishes, just `Runtime > Restart and Run All` for it to take effect.

I've made a simple roulette game environment below for testing. For the observation space, I've created a `gym.spaces.Dict()` which you will see (the code is well commented).

It trains just fine, but when it gets to the testing iteration,  I get the error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-7c2cb900b44f> in <module>
      6 obs = env.reset()
      7 for i in range(1000):
----> 8     action, _state = model.predict(obs, deterministic=True)
      9     obs, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
     10     env.render()

ValueError: Error: Unexpected observation shape () for Box environment, please use (1,) or (n_env, 1) for the observation shape.
```

I read somewhere that the dict space needs to be flattened with gym.wrappers.FlattenObservation, so I change this line:

```
    action, _state = model.predict(obs, deterministic=True)
```

...to:

```
    action, _state = model.predict(FlattenObservation(obs), deterministic=True)
```

...which results in this error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-87824c61fc45> in <module>
      6 obs = env.reset()
      7 for i in range(1000):
----> 8     action, _state = model.predict(FlattenObservation(obs), deterministic=True)
      9     obs, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
     10     env.render()

AttributeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'observation_space'
```

I've also tried doing this, which results in the same error as the last one:

```
obs = env.reset()
obs = FlattenObservation(obs)
```

So clearly I'm not doing something right, but I just don't know what it is as this'll be the first time I'm working with a `Dict` space.

```
import os, sys
if not os.path.isdir('/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/stable_baselines3'):
    !pip3 install stable_baselines3
    print("\n\n\n Stable Baselines3 has been installed, Restart and Run All now. DO NOT factory reset, or you'll have to start over\n")
    sys.exit(0)

from random import randint
from numpy import inf, float32, array, int32, int64
import gym
from gym.wrappers import FlattenObservation
from stable_baselines3 import A2C, DQN, PPO

"""Roulette environment class"""
class Roulette_Environment(gym.Env):

    metadata = {'render.modes': ['human', 'text']}

    """Initialize the environment"""
    def __init__(self):
        super(Roulette_Environment, self).__init__()

        # Some global variables
        self.max_table_limit = 1000
        self.initial_bankroll = 2000

        # Spaces
        # Each number on roulette board can have 0-1000 units placed on it
        self.action_space = gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=1000, shape=(37,))

        # We're going to keep track of how many times each number shows up
        # while we're playing, plus our current bankroll and the max
        # table betting limit so the agent knows how much $ in total is allowed
        # to be placed on the table. Going to use a Dict space for this.
        self.observation_space = gym.spaces.Dict(
            {
                "0": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "1": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "2": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "3": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "4": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "5": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "6": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "7": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "8": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "9": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "10": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "11": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "12": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "13": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "14": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "15": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "16": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "17": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "18": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "19": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "20": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "21": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "22": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "23": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "24": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "25": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "26": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "27": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "28": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "29": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "30": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "31": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "32": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "33": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "34": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "35": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "36": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                
                "current_bankroll": gym.spaces.Box(low=-inf, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                
                "max_table_limit": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
            }
        )

    """Reset the Environment"""
    def reset(self):
        self.current_bankroll = self.initial_bankroll
        self.done = False

        # Take a sample from the observation_space to modify the values of
        self.current_state = self.observation_space.sample()
        
        # Reset each number being tracked throughout gameplay to 0
        for i in range(0, 37):
            self.current_state[str(i)] = 0

        # Reset our globals
        self.current_state['current_bankroll'] = self.current_bankroll
        self.current_state['max_table_limit'] = self.max_table_limit
        
        return self.current_state


    """Step Through the Environment"""
    def step(self, action):
        
        # Convert actions to ints cuz they show up as floats,
        # even when defined as ints in the environment.
        # https://github.com/openai/gym/issues/3107
        for i in range(len(action)):
            action[i] = int(action[i])
        self.current_action = action
        
        # Subtract your bets from bankroll
        sum_of_bets = sum([bet for bet in self.current_action])

        # Spin the wheel
        self.current_number = randint(a=0, b=36)

        # Calculate payout/reward
        self.reward = 36 * self.current_action[self.current_number] - sum_of_bets

        self.current_bankroll += self.reward

        # Update the current state
        self.current_state['current_bankroll'] = self.current_bankroll
        self.current_state[str(self.current_number)] += 1

        # If we've doubled our money, or lost our money
        if self.current_bankroll >= self.initial_bankroll * 2 or self.current_bankroll <= 0:
            self.done = True

        return self.current_state, self.reward, self.done, {}


    """Render the Environment"""
    def render(self, mode='text'):
        # Text rendering
        if mode == "text":
            print(f'Bets Placed: {self.current_action}')
            print(f'Number rolled: {self.current_number}')
            print(f'Reward: {self.reward}')
            print(f'New Bankroll: {self.current_bankroll}')

env = Roulette_Environment()

model = PPO('MultiInputPolicy', env, verbose=1)
model.learn(total_timesteps=10000)

obs = env.reset()
# obs = FlattenObservation(obs)

for i in range(1000):
    action, _state = model.predict(obs, deterministic=True)
    # action, _state = model.predict(FlattenObservation(obs), deterministic=True)
    obs, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
    env.render()
    if done:
      obs = env.reset()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, `stable-baselines3` is pretty picky about the observation format.
I ran into the same problem the last days.
Some documentation as well as an [example model](https://stable-baselines3.readthedocs.io/en/master/_modules/stable_baselines3/common/envs/multi_input_envs.html#SimpleMultiObsEnv) helped me figure things out:

### It is possible to use Dict-observations

However, the `values` of `Box`-Spaces **must be mapped as `numpy.ndarrays` with correct `dtypes`.**
*For `Discrete` observations, the observation can also be passed as `int` value. However, I'm not completely sure if this still holds for multidimensional `MultiDiscrete`-spaces*

### A very simple solution

A solution to your example would be to replace code everytime you reassign a value of your Dict through:
`self.current_state[key] = np.array([value], dtype=int)`

Below you find a working implementation of your problem (my system has `Python=3.10` installed, though. But it should work on lower versions as well).

### Working code:

```py
import os, sys

from random import randint
from numpy import inf, float32, array, int32, int64
import gym
from gym.wrappers import FlattenObservation
from stable_baselines3 import A2C, DQN, PPO
import numpy as np

"""Roulette environment class"""
class Roulette_Environment(gym.Env):

    metadata = {'render.modes': ['human', 'text']}

    """Initialize the environment"""
    def __init__(self):
        super(Roulette_Environment, self).__init__()

        # Some global variables
        self.max_table_limit = 1000
        self.initial_bankroll = 2000

        # Spaces
        # Each number on roulette board can have 0-1000 units placed on it
        self.action_space = gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=1000, shape=(37,))

        # We're going to keep track of how many times each number shows up
        # while we're playing, plus our current bankroll and the max
        # table betting limit so the agent knows how much $ in total is allowed
        # to be placed on the table. Going to use a Dict space for this.
        self.observation_space = gym.spaces.Dict(
            {
                "0": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "1": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "2": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "3": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "4": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "5": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "6": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "7": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "8": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "9": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "10": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "11": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "12": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "13": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "14": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "15": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "16": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "17": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "18": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "19": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "20": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "21": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "22": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "23": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "24": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "25": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "26": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "27": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "28": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "29": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "30": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "31": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "32": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "33": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "34": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "35": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                "36": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                
                "current_bankroll": gym.spaces.Box(low=-inf, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
                
                "max_table_limit": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=inf, shape=(1,), dtype=int),
            }
        )

    """Reset the Environment"""
    def reset(self):
        self.current_bankroll = self.initial_bankroll
        self.done = False

        # Take a sample from the observation_space to modify the values of
        self.current_state = self.observation_space.sample()
        
        # Reset each number being tracked throughout gameplay to 0
        for i in range(0, 37):
            self.current_state[str(i)] = np.array([0], dtype=int)

        # Reset our globals
        self.current_state['current_bankroll'] = np.array([self.current_bankroll], dtype=int)
        self.current_state['max_table_limit'] = np.array([self.max_table_limit], dtype=int)
        
        return self.current_state


    """Step Through the Environment"""
    def step(self, action):
        
        # Convert actions to ints cuz they show up as floats,
        # even when defined as ints in the environment.
        # https://github.com/openai/gym/issues/3107
        for i in range(len(action)):
            action[i] = int(action[i])
        self.current_action = action
        
        # Subtract your bets from bankroll
        sum_of_bets = sum([bet for bet in self.current_action])

        # Spin the wheel
        self.current_number = randint(a=0, b=36)

        # Calculate payout/reward
        self.reward = 36 * self.current_action[self.current_number] - sum_of_bets

        self.current_bankroll += self.reward

        # Update the current state
        self.current_state['current_bankroll'] = np.array([self.current_bankroll], dtype=int)
        self.current_state[str(self.current_number)] += np.array([1], dtype=int)

        # If we've doubled our money, or lost our money
        if self.current_bankroll >= self.initial_bankroll * 2 or self.current_bankroll <= 0:
            self.done = True

        return self.current_state, self.reward, self.done, {}


    """Render the Environment"""
    def render(self, mode='text'):
        # Text rendering
        if mode == "text":
            print(f'Bets Placed: {self.current_action}')
            print(f'Number rolled: {self.current_number}')
            print(f'Reward: {self.reward}')
            print(f'New Bankroll: {self.current_bankroll}')

env = Roulette_Environment()

model = PPO('MultiInputPolicy', env, verbose=1)
model.learn(total_timesteps=10)

obs = env.reset()
# obs = FlattenObservation(obs)

for i in range(1000):
    action, _state = model.predict(obs, deterministic=True)
    # action, _state = model.predict(FlattenObservation(obs), deterministic=True)
    obs, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
    env.render()
    if done:
      obs = env.reset()
```

Answer (score 2):

You have 3 different issues here.

First, your main problem is in `reset` method. You've defined your items as boxes with a `shape=(1,)`. However, in `reset` you assign simply integers to your items, e.g., here `self.current_state[str(i)] = 0` and later for `current_bankroll` and `max_table_limit` keys. SB3's `BasePolicy`'s `predict` wraps your dict values with `np.array(your_integer_value)` that has a shape `()`, which ofc raises an exception since it is incompatible with your boxes shape. Change your initial values to 1-size arrays respectively, e.g., `self.current_state[str(i)] = [0]`. Also change your `step` method to update 1-size lists, not integers. That will solve your issue with shape inadequacy.

Second, you can actually get rid off `Dict` by manually flattening all your single-shape `Box`es into a single one. Your `low` will turn into a list respectively (if you change your `current_bankroll` value's `low` to 0, then you even don't need to edit `low` as well, it can be further an integer).

Third, other than above mentioned your env looks correct. However, there's a bug in sb3. I assume you've installed sb3 with pip using the latest 1.6.2 tag (10th October). In this version there is a bug restricting a type of observation in `BaseAlgortihm.predict` to `np.ndarray` only, which was [later  fixed](https://github.com/DLR-RM/stable-baselines3/commit/4fb8aec215fd2dd5d668aae8285937c268baca97#diff-dfc87af8939583eaa2e8329958b7bb21f6471d567ad6680b4e2db7886dbb2936L514) in the master branch. So install sb3 from a git directly.

Answer (score 1):

`FlattenObservation()` takes env as an argument, you should use it like
`env = FlattenObservation(env)`, then proceed to model learn and predict.